# Setting fillcolor dynamically in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, openstreetmap, leaflet, polygons

Hello Excellent folks of Stackoverflow,
Thank you in advance for taking the time to read and help.

I'm using the interactive chloropath example for leaflet.js

I figured out how to make each of my polygons add a running tally of values to the bottom of the page after each polygon is clicked.

Upon clicking a selected polygon a second time it removes it's value from the running tally.

I'd like to visually represent this as a fillcolor change of the polygons on the map.

[EDIT]: So basically, when I "unclick" an already highlighted polygon, it successfully removes it's count from the running tally, but it doesn't "un-highlight" it. That is the challenge.....

Here's my code so far (javascript with PHP included):
(I've included comments within my code to explain what I'm trying to do. Again any help would be greatly appreciated)

```
function addUp(num, x)
 {  


<?php 
// begin php code

$places = $db->query("SELECT boundary_id, boundary_name FROM boundaries WHERE       boundary_state= '$thatstate'");


while($row = $places->fetch_object()){ 

//end php code ?>



//begin javascript
if (x == "List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?>" && List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?> == 1) {


temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;

tempo = parseInt(temp);

numo = parseInt(num);

nwTemp = tempo + numo;

document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;

geojson.setStyle({fillColor: 'blue'}); // I want to set color to blue to show highlighted


List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?> = 0;

return List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?>;
}


if (x == "List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?>" && List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?> == 0) {


temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;

tempo = parseInt(temp);

numo = parseInt(num);

nwTemp = tempo - numo;

document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;


geojson.resetStyle; // I want to reset color of polygon if deselected (this would be the default)

List<?php echo $row->boundary_name ?> = 1; 
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you point out exactly in your post what you want to do (just setting a different highlight color?) and what is currently not working.

Comment: Thank you MaM, added [Edit] to question, here it is again:  So basically, when I "unclick" an already highlighted polygon, it successfully removes it's count from the running tally, but it doesn't "un-highlight" it. That is the challenge.....